# Creating multicolored line chart in angular nativescript

Tags: nativescript

How to create a multicolored line chart with nativescript. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk8bi.png)

Answer (score 1):

I guess for each color you like to apply, you will have to define a separate LineSeries and Palette.

**Example**

```
<RadCartesianChart>

    <CategoricalAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis></CategoricalAxis>

    <LinearAxis tkCartesianVerticalAxis>
    </LinearAxis>

    <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries selectionMode="Series"
        [items]="categoricalSource1" categoryProperty="Country"
        valueProperty="Amount">
    </LineSeries>

    <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries selectionMode="Series"
        [items]="categoricalSource2" categoryProperty="Country"
        valueProperty="Amount">
    </LineSeries>

    <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries selectionMode="Series"
        [items]="categoricalSource3" categoryProperty="Country"
        valueProperty="Amount">
    </LineSeries>

    <Palette tkCartesianPalette>
        <PaletteEntry tkCartesianPaletteEntry strokeWidth="5"
            strokeColor="Orange"></PaletteEntry>
        <PaletteEntry tkCartesianPaletteEntry strokeWidth="5"
            strokeColor="Blue"></PaletteEntry>
        <PaletteEntry tkCartesianPaletteEntry strokeWidth="5"
            strokeColor="Pink"></PaletteEntry>
    </Palette>

</RadCartesianChart>
```

[Refer advanced styling example on Github](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/master/chart/app/examples/styling/chart-styling-selection.component.html)

Comment: Using multiple line charts is not feasible. Is there any way to do it in the single line chart?

Comment: I don't think so. That may be a question for GitHub UI feedback repo, the plugins are not open source so they may only have some clear answer here.